# How can i change the backgroundcolor via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I need your help:

I got a website and i want to change the `bg-coler` while hovering over the menu (like on the rhcp-website) and i already tried it with jquery but it did not work..

(Just to be clear, i do not want to change the background color of the div container which contains my menu it should be the whole body..--> code)

Thank you!

Code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.start').hover(function () {
        $('html').css('background-color', '#676767')
    });
</script>

<?php include_once 'template.php' ?>

<title>Maximilian Braun</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="start">
        <h1>
            <a href="actor.php" >Schauspieler</a> - <a href="foto.php">Fotograf</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <?php echo footer();?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to wrap your code inside the `document's ready` handler,

```
$(function(){
 $('.start').hover(function(){$('html').css('background-color','#676767') } );
});
```

Since Jquery cannot recognize the element with class `start` while the relevant element not got loaded.

Comment: thank you very much! (:
so simple :D

is it possible to do this with images as bg? i already tried to use `background`instead of `background-color`

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer + explanation**

Your code was not working because you were using jQuery before the document had finished loading, always wrap your code either with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code goes here
}
```

or:

```
$(function(){
    //your code goes here
}
```

Simply use as [Rajaprabhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209018/rajaprabhu-aravindasamy) suggested:

```
$(function(){
 $('.start').hover(function(){
   $('html').css('background-color','#676767') } );
});
```

**Getting the color to animate**

The [RHCP website](http://redhotchilipeppers.com/) however does not only change the color, but also animates this change. jQuery can not animate colors. You can solve this in two ways. One is to use a jQuery plugin, the other is to use CSS transitions.

*Plugin*

If you import a plugin like [jQuery Color](http://code.jquery.com/color/) you can use:

```
$(function(){
 $('.start').hover(function(){
   $('html').animate({backgroundColor: '#676767') } );
});
```

*CSS Transitions*

Instead of having a plugin take care of the animation, you can also use CSS animations, which will take care of transitioning between changing color values.

Use the original code:

```
$(function(){
 $('.start').hover(function(){
   $('html').css('background-color','#676767') } );
});
```

And use the following CSS

```
.start {
   -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;  /* Android 2.1+, Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6  */
           transition: background-color 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+  */
}
```

PS: if you do use CSS transitions, do note IE 9 and below does not support CSS Transitions.

Comment: hey, thank you!
:)

with this animate thing..
I did the following:

`<scriptsrc="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

                                                       $(function(){
     $('.start').hover(function(){
       $('html').animate({background-Color: '#676767') } );
    });
    </script>`
but it does not work ;/

Comment: @MaximilianBraun: believe you should use ```backgroundColor``` and not ```background-Color```

Comment: I have no idea why then. I've created a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/b63w3/) here, see if you can get it to work looking at that example.

Comment: thank you..! 
i just missed one `});`
dont know why :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be inside dom ready

```
$(function() {
        $('.start').hover(function(){$('html').css('background-color','#676767') } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call this when you DOM is ready, so put it inside `$(function()..` and also put `;` at the end of `$('html').css('background-color','#676767')`.

```
$(function(){
    $('.start').hover(function(){$('html').css('background-color','#676767'); } );
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eu9rV/141/)**

Answer (score 0):

By using .ready( handler ) you can solve you issue:
All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
- $( document ).ready( handler )
- $().ready( handler ) (this is not recommended)
- $( handler )
```

$( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

```
$('.start').hover(function(){$('html').css('background-color','#676767') } );
```

});